# How can this vector be optimized 10 times faster when using O2 in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, compiler-optimization, stdvector

This is my code:

```
while (vector0.size())
{
    for (ii = vector0.begin(); ii != vector0.end(); ii++) 
        if  (table[*ii] > table[*max]) max = ii;

    /*
     Here I add push_back something to vector and erase something from vector.
    */
}
```

The hot code is the `for` loop and `if` statement.

If I enable `-O2` or `-O3` in gcc (and also in clang) it will become about 10 times faster.
I would like to know why and how this happened.

Comment: `-S`  is your friend. Compare the asm dumps.

Comment: There are A LOT of optimisations involved from switching from `-O0` to either `-O2` or `-O3`. Explaining those would have to cover a whole lot of ground. It is a too vast of a subject.

Comment: What are the types of `vector0`, `ii`, `table` and `max`?

Answer (score 1):

Only 10 times? Bummer. The biggest optimization I'd expect is the removal of a range check on `operator[]`, which in turn makes it inline-able. Furthermore, the `end` call can be inlined as well (`begin` is called once so it's a don't care).

BTW, just call `std::max_element`.

Answer (score 0):

Templates generate *a lot* of code. Most of this code could be safely removed, but it is costly process that is performed only on higher optimisation levels.

Actual optimisations performed depends on compiler and invocation flags, but it is function inlining and dead code elimination that produces very significant difference in your case.